# How to create custom JSON-API resource drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I have issues with creating custom JSON API resource which will be visible on mydrupalsite/jsonapi link.
I have found this example:

https://glamanate.com/blog/using-json-api-query-your-search-api-indexes

which shows how to create custom resource but it is outdated. I tried to make a custom module looking in this article, but it doesn't work anymore because json-api module has changed.

For example, I want to show all nodes and make the jsonapi endpoint of type nodes--all which will serve all the nodes of my Drupal site.

I am using drupal 8.7.1 and JSON API core module.

I have tried to google this problem, but there are no examples for creating custom json api endpoints.

For final result i want to make jsonapi endpoint for example: mydrupalsite/jsonapi/nodes/all which will serve all nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You could declare REST endpoints within a custom module.

In /modules/custom/mymodule/src/Plugin/rest/resrouce/MyEndPoints.php, create a class extending ResourceBase, according to https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources.

Then you could define which set of nodes you want to expose, use query parameters to filter them, paginate, or do whatever you want.

See also : https://medium.com/@emerico/create-custom-rest-resource-for-get-and-post-method-in-drupal-8-e445330be3ff

I successfully used this technique to get events displayed with [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) library, I can elaborate on this if it helps.

Good luck with it

Comment: Yeah, I know how to add custom resource endpoint with REST. I was looking for solution with JSON-API module becouse my front end is in Gatsby.js so i'm pulling drupal content with gatsby-source-drupal plugin which uses JSON-API module.
Thank you for your reply!
I hope creating custom resource will be added in JSON-API module soon.

Answer (score 1):

The module does not currently support external connection to its internal-use-only API according to the JSON:API's module maintainers, hence why your referenced module does not work anymore.

There are plans for the mixed bundle you are requesting. See the thread below for the discussion.

https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras/issues/2956414

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I hope it will be added to JSON-API module soon.

Answer (score 1):

### Checkout [JSON:API Cross Bundles](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_cross_bundles)

> We discussed this in Decoupled Days 2019. We came to the following
> conclussions:
>
> - We will put this under a different contrib as per my request ☺️ `jsonapi_cross_bundles`
> - There will only be support for GET
> - The edge cases in filtering will be solved using whatever stance Entity Query API uses.
> - In parallel we'll create a JSON:API issue to add a payload to the 404 routes like `/jsonapi/node` that will contain: (a) a list of links
>   to the resource types for that entity type, and (b) link to a
>   documentation page explaining the cross bundle situation (maybe even
>   mentioning the experimental `jsonapi_cross_bundles` module).
>
> Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras/issues/2956414#comment-13189872

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, the best way to do this is the [JSON:API Resources module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources).

This module allows you to add your own JSON:API endpoints in a custom module.

There are several [examples of how to define your own resources](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/jsonapi_resources/tree/8.x-1.x/tests/modules/jsonapi_resources_test/src/Resource).